# Unable to get refresh token for google Oauth2 with xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, google-api, xamarin.android, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement google authentication in my xamarin android app.  I am using OAuth2Authenticator to authenticate my user and after authentication it only returns access_token.How do i get refresh_token so that the user dont have to login each time he opens the app?

I have been using the following code to authenticate the user

```
 var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
            clientId: "***************************.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
            authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"),
            redirectUrl: new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me"),
            accessTokenUrl: newUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"),
            clientSecret: "*********************",
            getUsernameAsync: null);


auth.Completed += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (!e.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Fail to authenticate!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    return;
                }
                string access_token;
                e.Account.Properties.TryGetValue("access_token", out access_token);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself to solve the issue? Please add the code you're using to achieve your goal.

Comment: @Demitrian I added the code i am using to request the accesstoken and refresh token above! Please have a look

Comment: @Ginna, Are you saying that the response does not have a response token or that you don't know how extracted it form the response?

Comment: @Nkosi The response does not have a refresh token it only has an accesstoken .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there are some issues with Xamarin.Auth and Google due to Google no longer recommending using the app's built in WebView for login and instead one should use the devices browser. See Google's article on this:

https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html

If you do use a WebView built in to the app, as Xamarin.Auth does by default, you will not get a refresh token as (per the article linked above):

> In contrast, the outdated method of using embedded browsers for OAuth means a user must sign-in to Google each time, instead of using the existing logged-in session from the device.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin Auth doesn't support refresh_token

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/pull/79

I implemeted an inherated class you can find on my [gist](https://gist.github.com/lewixlabs/6addc59de22318400a3a9691078ecb33)

It works for my custom identity provider (refresh_token is returned in params).
You can try my solution.

Hi!
Lewix