# How do I setup a listener for Xamarin.Firebase.Auth AddIdTokenListner

Tags: android, xamarin, firebase-authentication

I recently started learning Xamarin and was following through some tutorials that show how to use Xamarin.Firebase.Auth nuget package to handle authentication. I was able to login and get the Id Token at that point without a problem.

I also want to use an api that I have built that uses the token for it's JWT. I've used Firebase before and know that their id tokens expire after one hour. So I looked around for a tutorial on how to setup my code to handle the token changes, but couldn't find anything. I started going through the code and the only thing I could find was a method to add an Id Token Listener. So, I put together a Listener class.

```
public class IdTokenListener : Java.Lang.Object, FirebaseAuth.IIdTokenListener
{
    public EventHandler<TokenChangedEventArgs> IdTokenChanged;

    public class TokenChangedEventArgs: EventArgs
    {
        public string Token { get; set; }
    }
    public void OnIdTokenChanged(FirebaseAuth auth)
    {
        auth.CurrentUser.GetIdToken(false).AsAsync<GetTokenResult>().ContinueWith((task) =>
        {
            IdTokenChanged?.Invoke(this, new TokenChangedEventArgs { Token = task.Result.Token });
        });

    }

}
```

Then in the MainActivity.cs file of the Android project (haven't worked on the iOS project yet), I created a class level variable to hold an instance of the listener. I also called the AddIdTokenListener method as well as adding an event handler within the OnCreate method:

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    IdTokenListener idTokenListener = new IdTokenListener();

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Other code removed for space
        FirebaseAuth.Instance.AddIdTokenListener(idTokenListener);
        idTokenListener.IdTokenChanged += OnIdTokenChanged;
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }

    private void OnIdTokenChanged(object sender, IdTokenListener.TokenChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main Activity - OnIdTokenChanged: " + e.Token);
    }

}
```

When the app loads or I use the login page, the token listener is called and I get the expected results. However, if I leave the app running, the token listener is never called again. I even left it running overnight just to make sure it wasn't a timing issue. Is there something else I need to do in order to get this to work?

Comment: the id tokens expire after one hour, so you mean that token listener is never called again when  id tokens expire?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I suggest you an try to creating one class that inheriting `FirebaseInstanceIdService`, override `OnTokenRefresh` function to get fresh token. Please take a look [Implement the Firebase Instance ID Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows#implement-the-firebase-instance-id-service)

Comment: I went through the link you provided and it deals with getting the FCM token, not the OAuth token.

Comment: About get refresh Auth token, I find one thread that you can take a look:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984255/unable-to-get-refresh-token-for-google-oauth2-with-xamarin-android